# How 2 find aphelion, mean distance from the sun, and equation for elliptical orbit. Known: perihelion and distance from the center of orbit to the sun

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The perihelion of Pluto is 4551 million miles, and the distance from the center of its elliptical orbit to the sun is 897.5 million miles. Find the aphelion of Pluto. What is the mean distance of Pluto from the Sun? Write an equation to represent the orbit of Pluto around the Sun.

Comment: What have you done so far? You've typed in a statement of the problem here, I can see that. Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: I have not been able to do much so far, since I don't know what equation to use for this. I have a diagram showing the sun, aphelion, perihelion, and distance from the center of its elliptical orbit to the sun, with value of perihelion and distance from the center of its elliptical orbit to the sun written on it.

Comment: You need to find equations that relate these values with the eccentricity of the orbit.  Find a figure of an ellipse showing the foci and the center.

Comment: @RossMillikan The foci would be 897.5 million miles from the center. I believe I found that the semimajor axis/mean distance of Pluto from the sun is 5448.5 million miles after adding 897.5 million miles to the perihelion, which I think means that the aphelion must be 6346 million miles after adding 897.5 million miles to the semimajor axis. I found an equation: e=c/a, where c is distance from center to foci, and a is center to vertex. I think eccentricity is about .164724236028. How do I find the equation for orbit?

Comment: if you know minor & major axes, use general equation of the ellipse: $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. This is the simplest model without accounting for other planets.

Comment: Thank you so much RossMillikan and Vasya. I finished the problem. (x2/29686152.25+y2/28880646=1)